# Can't add custom Forge integration with Document Management to BIM 360 account

Tags: autodesk-forge

I have an issue with access integration of Forge and BIM 360.
This account has paid Docs license and Forge paid tokens.
The forge app was created.
All the 11 services are activated in the Forge app.

When I click on adding integration it shows me this window.
[Custom integration options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6tTXM.png)
But there should be “Document Management” checkbox also, right?
Now I have "BIM 360 Account administration” checkbox only

I’ve tried to call endpoints anyway.

So I can access projects without a problem using this endpoint. It works ok.
https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/reference/http/projects-GET/

But if I want to get files from the project and the specific folder it gives me an 403 error
https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/projects-project_id-folders-folder_id-contents-GET/
Example of returned json
{"jsonapi":{"version":"1.0"},"errors":[{"id":"74dadd7c-2191-471c-8e42-c4ca2af30ab1","status":"403","detail":"Forbidden"}]}

I've expected this endpoint work and return me content of the specific folder of the project
https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/projects-project_id-folders-folder_id-contents-GET/

Answer (score 0):

If you are on an enterprise plan and the Apps or Custom Integration features are not enabled, send an email to bim360appsactivations@autodesk.com to request access
Ref: https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/bim-360/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/ENU/BIM360D-Administration/files/About-Account-Admin/GUID-0C83B441-C611-4574-8DA0-45D5CFC235FA-html.html